Oracle accumulate values with condition
below is an extract of an Oracle table with these columns:



ID
WeekStartDate
AbsentFrom
AbsentTo




1
01-JAN-24
null
null


1
08-JAN-24
09-JAN-24
17-JAN-24


1
15-JAN-24
09-JAN-24
17-JAN-24


1
22-JAN-24
null
null


1
29-JAN-24
30-JAN-24
11-FEB-24


1
05-FEB-24
30-JAN-24
11-FEB-24


1
12-FEB-24
null
null



I want to add a new column called AbsentDays, it checks how many days of absence during a week and then accumulates absent days all the way for the entire period and for each id:



ID
WeekStartDate
AbsentFrom
AbsentTo
TotalAbsentDays




1
01-JAN-24
null
null
0


1
08-JAN-24
09-JAN-24
17-JAN-24
6


1
15-JAN-24
09-JAN-24
17-JAN-24
9


1
22-JAN-24
null
null
9


1
29-JAN-24
30-JAN-24
11-FEB-24
15


1
05-FEB-24
30-JAN-24
11-FEB-24
22


1
12-FEB-24
null
null
22



The data in the table is huge, for performance purpose, is there a way to achieve this result without using recursion?
I tried LAG, LAST_Value, sum(), but couldn't get the desired result. Please help. Thanks.

You can use GREATEST and LEAST to find the start- and end- dates within the week and calculate the difference to find the days absence each week and then use the SUM analytic function to generate a cumulative total:
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(
         COALESCE(
           LEAST(absentto + 1, weekstartdate + 7)
           - GREATEST(absentfrom, weekstartdate),
           0
         )
       ) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY weekstartdate)
         AS total_days_absent
FROM   table_name t

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, WeekStartDate, AbsentFrom, AbsentTo) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-01', NULL,              NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-08', DATE '2024-01-09', DATE '2024-01-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-15', DATE '2024-01-09', DATE '2024-01-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-22', NULL,              NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-29', DATE '2024-01-30', DATE '2024-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-05', DATE '2024-01-30', DATE '2024-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-12', NULL,              NULL              FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
WEEKSTARTDATE
ABSENTFROM
ABSENTTO
TOTAL_DAYS_ABSENT




1
2024-01-01 00:00:00
null
null
0


1
2024-01-08 00:00:00
2024-01-09 00:00:00
2024-01-17 00:00:00
6


1
2024-01-15 00:00:00
2024-01-09 00:00:00
2024-01-17 00:00:00
9


1
2024-01-22 00:00:00
null
null
9


1
2024-01-29 00:00:00
2024-01-30 00:00:00
2024-02-11 00:00:00
15


1
2024-02-05 00:00:00
2024-01-30 00:00:00
2024-02-11 00:00:00
22


1
2024-02-12 00:00:00
null
null
22



fiddle
